# View user names inside groups WSS 3.0

Tags: permissions, wss-3.0, user-accounts

When I click on users an groups inside WSS 3.0 I just get a "IT Members" entry in the list that pops up. How do I drill down and find out who is exactly in that group? I see no options for listing members of any group within any of the SharePoint site groups. Theres gotta be a way to view membership.
Image 1 shows the list I get. Image 2 shows what I get When I click on Members....it doesn't list any users.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Is that group an Active Directory group?

Comment: Yes. This particular one is, but not all are. i'm looking for a list of users. Do I have to look in active directory for all of them

Comment: Some of the groups I'm finding are not in Active Directory